# Determining if a set of complex numbers spans

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

I've just started to learn about complex numbers and I got stuch at this question:

Let's look at the vector space $$V=C^2.$$
Does the set $${(1 -i, 1 + i),(1 + i, 1 - i)}$$ spans V while V is a vector space above R?

First of all, I didnt understand this question very well. $$V=C^2.$$ What does it mean "V is above R"?
Second, how do i prove span of a set of complex numbers?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a real vector space; you just use the usual addition of vectors and the usual product of a vector by a real number. With these operations, it becomes a vector space over $\mathbb R$. This vector space has a basis consisting of $4$ vectors: $(1,0)$, $(i,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(0,i)$. Therefore $\dim V=4$ and so no set with only $2$ vectors can span it.

Comment: How did you find the basis?

Comment: @user534957 If $(a+bi,c+di)\in\mathbb{C}^2$, then$$(a+bi,c+di)=a(1,0)+b(i,0)+c(0,1)+d(0,i).$$